# Is there any possiblity how to work with linq All, Any and <List>

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am creating tests in in C# using selenium and Specflow.

I started to use linq and I am wondering if there is some simple way how I can work with Any, All, Where etc. and lists together.
I know that it returns TRUE or False, but it would be really nice if I could use it somehow with lists.

Example: There is plenty of items and only one of them is without URL, so in the elements I can see there is no a href for it, so I have chosen elements by CssSelector and there are items and as I said - ONE OF THEM WITHOUT URL

So I created this:

```
    public bool IsItemWithoutURL()
        {
            bool emptyUrlItems = items.Any(i => String.IsNullOrEmpty((i.GetAttribute("href"))));
            return emptyUrlItems;
        }
```

This will return me true or false, but my goal is to take that one item and work with him. For example click on it etc.

Is there any way for it?

Comment: So you had three methods that seemed like they might be relevant.  You tried one, and it didn't do what you wanted.  What happened when you tried using the other two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LINQ Any and All methods are not a good fit if you want to return found item, because they only answer the question if Any or All items in collection satisfy provided predicate. You could use for example

1. First - returns first element that satisfies the provided predicate, throws exception if there's no such element (use FirstOrDefault if you want to return null instead of throwing exception)
2. Where - returns elements that satisfy the provided predicate or empty collection if none are found

Example:

```
public ITEM_TYPE GetFirstItemWithoutURL()
{
    return items.First(i => string.IsNullOrEmpty(i.GetAttribute("href")));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public bool IsAnyItemWithoutURL()
 {
        var emptyItem = items.FirstOrDefault(i => String.IsNullOrEmpty((i.GetAttribute("href"))));

        //here you can do everything you want with emptyItem because it's not boolean.
        return emptyItem != null;
}
```